# Setting user agent on firefox with protractor and using seleniumAddress does not work

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor, user-agent

I want to set a specific user agent using protractor and Firefox. If I use directConnect on protractor.conf.js, it works:

```js
//selenium-webdriver is installed via npm
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var firefoxProfile = new firefox.Profile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", 'monitoring1152936086');

exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'firefox_profile': firefoxProfile
    },
    ...
}
```

However, if I use seleniumAddress instead of directConnect it does not work. Test does work but the user agent is not used. I need to use a selenium server. For example:

```js
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var firefoxProfile = new firefox.Profile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", 'monitoring1152936086');

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'firefox_profile': firefoxProfile
    },
    ...
}
```

As a side note, I cannot use chrome since I am trying to use Firefox as a workaround to the not so stable combination of protractor and selenium-docker with chrome (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2678 for this reported as an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the direct connect case Protractor creates the browser itself, so it's able to have total configuration over the browser.  In the remote case Protractor has less control because it's connecting to the selenium server started up by `webdriver-manager`.  The correct time to pass a firefox profile would be when `webdriver-manager` starts, but Protractor does not currently provide this feature.